# How to clear the screen after exiting less, man and vim

Tags: vim, manpage, less-unix

When I exit from the man page, less and vim the screen doesn't *clear*. I don't mean the *clear* command rather I want to see the previous screen that I entered before the man or less.

There is a `less -X` (`--no-init`) command that doesn't clear the screen after exiting, but there are not any aliases for the less command on my system and I want the inverse of this option.

My terminal picture:

[image: screenshot]

As it clear, I can see the less output even after I exit from it.

Comment: Do `tput smcup` and `tput rmcup` work?  ie, does your terminal even have the capability?

Comment: No, it didn't work. I remembered in the past that it was correct!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60499/how-to-set-the-bash-display-to-not-show-the-vim-text-after-exit

Comment: Is the issue resolved? I had the same issue and I noticed that env variable LESS is set to -X.

Comment: @Valadri my problem solved by removing the TERM environment variable in the .bashrc

Answer (score 3):

My problem was solved by removing the TERM environment variable in the .bashrc.